# Replacing content of one site to another in Squarespace

Tags: squarespace

I had a site on squarespace with the Business Plan and a custom domain linked to it. Then I decided to design the website from scratch, now I have two sites, the later with the trial version with which I can't link my custom domain.

So is there away? To replace the contents of the old site with the new one on squarespace?
Plus, do I have to pay for the business pl an for the new site or can I use the old site's?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to replace content from one Squarespace site to another using only the officially-provided tools.

It is possible to copy collection/page data from one site to another using a [Chrome Extension written by a 3rd party developer](https://www.squarewebsites.org/squarespacewebsites-tools-extension-pro/). I do not have first-hand experience with the tool; I do not believe it will enable you to copy all data from one site to another in one fell swoop, but rather one collection/page-at-a-time.

It may be simpler, faster and more reliable (and perhaps even less expensive) to pay for a plan on the new site, and [move your custom domain to the new site](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205812098-Moving-a-domain-between-sites) (the specific steps vary based on various factors including where your domain is registered, whether you have GSuite connected, etc.):

> - For Squarespace Domains, use the Move Domain to Another Website button.
> - For third-party domains, disconnect the domain and re-connect it to your new site.

You could of course then cancel your existing site, but you'd be out that money if it's outside [their refund period](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205810508-Cancelling-a-website-subscription#toc-refunds).